# ERC20 Token not valid anymore (please help)

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, crowdsale

I am using remix.ethereum.org as my compiler. I have already done some tests with the token contract before, and it worked. but since a few days, on wallet.ethereum.org, when I add the token after creating it it doesn't show the balancec anymore (just 0,0000...). So I tried to use MyEtherWallet, to send the tokens to the crowdsale address. And bam! There it says that my ERC20Token is not valid. 
Now as I can't find the issue, I would be very grateful if somebody could help me here, and I would send 0.1 ETH as a reward to the guy who finds the issue.
Here the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.12;

/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}


/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;


  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);


  /**
   * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
   * account.
   */
  function Ownable() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
  }
}

/**
 * @title ERC20Basic
 * @dev Simpler version of ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/179
 */
contract ERC20Basic {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) public constant returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}


/**
 * @title Basic token
 * @dev Basic version of StandardToken, with no allowances.
 */
contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));

    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }
}

/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public constant returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}


/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * @dev https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 * @dev Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;


  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));

    uint256 _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    // Check is not needed because sub(_allowance, _value) will already throw if this condition is not met
    // require (_value <= _allowance);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   *
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  /**
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   */
  function increaseApproval (address _spender, uint _addedValue)
    returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  function decreaseApproval (address _spender, uint _subtractedValue)
    returns (bool success) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }
}


/**
 * @title Burnable Token
 * @dev Token that can be irreversibly burned (destroyed).
 */
contract BurnableToken is StandardToken {

    event Burn(address indexed burner, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Burns a specific amount of tokens.
     * @param _value The amount of token to be burned.
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public {
        require(_value > 0);
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
        // no need to require value <= totalSupply, since that would imply the
        // sender's balance is greater than the totalSupply, which *should* be an assertion failure

        address burner = msg.sender;
        balances[burner] = balances[burner].sub(_value);
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_value);
        Burn(burner, _value);
    }
}

contract ImmortalityIvars is BurnableToken, Ownable {
  //this is token customize it after that we will deploy ICO - ok, understood. So just change name symbol etc right?yes ok

    string public constant name = "Immortality Ivars";
    string public constant symbol = "IMIV";
    uint public constant decimals = 6;
    uint256 public constant initialSupply = 1000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

    // Constructor
    function ImmortalityIvars() {
        totalSupply = initialSupply;
        balances[msg.sender] = initialSupply; // Send all tokens to owner
    }
}
```

Okay, I edited it to the question now - and tried to format it, don't know if it worked.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

/** * @title SafeMath * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error */ library SafeMath { function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) { uint256 c = a * b; assert(a == 0 || c / a == b); return c; }

function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) { // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0 uint256 c = a / b; uint256 c = a / b; // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold return c; }

function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) { assert(b <= a); return a - b; }

function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) { uint256 c = a + b; assert(c >= a); return c; } }

/** * @title Crowdsale * @dev Crowdsale is a base contract for managing a token crowdsale. * Crowdsales have a start and end timestamps, where investors can make * token purchases and the crowdsale will assign them tokens based * on a token per ETH rate. Funds collected are forwarded to a wallet * as they arrive. */ contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount){ } } contract Crowdsale { using SafeMath for uint256;

// uint256 durationInMinutes; // address where funds are collected address public wallet; // token address address public addressOfTokenUsedAsReward;

uint256 public price = 200;//initial price

token tokenReward;

mapping (address => uint) public contributions;

// start and end timestamps where investments are allowed (both inclusive) // uint256 public startTime; // uint256 public endTime; // amount of raised money in wei uint256 public weiRaised; uint256 public tokensSold;

/** * event for token purchase logging * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens * @param beneficiary who got the tokens * @param value weis paid for purchase * @param amount amount of tokens purchased */ event TokenPurchase(address indexed purchaser, address indexed beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);

function Crowdsale() { //DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE THIS //This is the wallet where all the ETH will go! wallet = 0x1E84B88b8AB048ff2Bf20284EC95217ce4f87B89;//this should be Filips wallet! // durationInMinutes = _durationInMinutes; //Here will come the checksum address we got addressOfTokenUsedAsReward = 0x39607EAc1EF8e9e931970a1522245779e45c866f; //address of the token contract //web3.toChecksumAddress is needed here in most cases.

tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);

}

bool public started = false;

function startSale(){ if (msg.sender != wallet) throw; started = true; }

function stopSale(){ if(msg.sender != wallet) throw; started = false; }

function setPrice(uint256 _price){ if(msg.sender != wallet) throw; price = _price; }

// fallback function can be used to buy tokens function () payable { buyTokens(msg.sender); }

// low level token purchase function function buyTokens(address beneficiary) payable { require(beneficiary != 0x0); require(validPurchase());

uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

if(tokensSold < 10000*10**6){
  price = 300;      
}else if(tokensSold < 20000*10**6){
  price = 273;
}else if(tokensSold < 30000*10**6){
  price = 249;
}else if(tokensSold < 40000*10**6){
  price = 228;
}else if(tokensSold < 50000*10**6){
  price = 209;
}else if(tokensSold < 60000*10**6){
  price = 192;
}else if(tokensSold < 70000*10**6){
  price = 177;
}else if(tokensSold < 80000*10**6){
  price = 164;
}else if(tokensSold < 90000*10**6){
  price = 153;
}else if(tokensSold < 100000*10**6){
  price = 143;
}else if(tokensSold < 110000*10**6){
  price = 135;
}else if(tokensSold < 120000*10**6){
  price = 128;
}else if(tokensSold < 130000*10**6){
  price = 122;
}else if(tokensSold < 140000*10**6){
  price = 116;
}else if(tokensSold < 150000*10**6){
  price = 111;
}else if(tokensSold < 160000*10**6){
  price = 106;
}else if(tokensSold < 170000*10**6){
  price = 102;
}else if(tokensSold < 180000*10**6){
  price = 98;
}else if(tokensSold < 190000*10**6){
  price = 94;
}else if(tokensSold < 200000*10**6){
  price = 91;
}else if(tokensSold < 210000*10**6){
  price = 88;
}else if(tokensSold < 220000*10**6){
  price = 86;
}else if(tokensSold < 230000*10**6){
  price = 84;
}else if(tokensSold < 240000*10**6){
  price = 82;
}else if(tokensSold < 250000*10**6){
  price = 80;
}else if(tokensSold < 260000*10**6){
  price = 78;
}else if(tokensSold < 270000*10**6){
  price = 76;
}else if(tokensSold < 280000*10**6){
  price = 74;
}else if(tokensSold < 290000*10**6){
  price = 72;
}else if(tokensSold < 300000*10**6){
  price = 70;
}else if(tokensSold < 310000*10**6){
  price = 68;
}else if(tokensSold < 320000*10**6){
  price = 66;
}else if(tokensSold < 330000*10**6){
  price = 64;
}else if(tokensSold < 340000*10**6){
  price = 62;
}else if(tokensSold < 350000*10**6){
  price = 60;
}else if(tokensSold < 360000*10**6){
  price = 58;
}else if(tokensSold < 370000*10**6){
  price = 56;
}else if(tokensSold < 380000*10**6){
  price = 54;
}else if(tokensSold < 390000*10**6){
  price = 52;
}else if(tokensSold < 400000*10**6){
  price = 50;
}else if(tokensSold < 410000*10**6){
  price = 49;
}else if(tokensSold < 420000*10**6){
  price = 48;
}else if(tokensSold < 430000*10**6){
  price = 47;
}else if(tokensSold < 440000*10**6){
  price = 46;
}else if(tokensSold < 450000*10**6){
  price = 45;
}else if(tokensSold < 460000*10**6){
  price = 44;
}else if(tokensSold < 470000*10**6){
  price = 43;
}else if(tokensSold < 480000*10**6){
  price = 42;
}else if(tokensSold < 490000*10**6){
  price = 41;
}else if(tokensSold < 500000*10**6){
  price = 40;
}else if(tokensSold < 510000*10**6){
  price = 39;
}else if(tokensSold < 520000*10**6){
  price = 38;
}else if(tokensSold < 530000*10**6){
  price = 37;
}else if(tokensSold < 540000*10**6){
  price = 36;
}else if(tokensSold < 550000*10**6){
  price = 35;
}else if(tokensSold < 560000*10**6){
  price = 34;
}else if(tokensSold < 570000*10**6){
  price = 33;
}else if(tokensSold < 580000*10**6){
  price = 32;
}else if(tokensSold < 590000*10**6){
  price = 31;
}else if(tokensSold < 600000*10**6){
  price = 30;
}else if(tokensSold < 610000*10**6){
  price = 29;
}else if(tokensSold < 620000*10**6){
  price = 28;
}else if(tokensSold < 630000*10**6){
  price = 27;
}else if(tokensSold < 640000*10**6){
  price = 26;
}else if(tokensSold < 650000*10**6){
  price = 25;
}else if(tokensSold < 660000*10**6){
  price = 24;
}else if(tokensSold < 670000*10**6){
  price = 23;
}else if(tokensSold < 680000*10**6){
  price = 22;
}else if(tokensSold < 690000*10**6){
  price = 21;
}else if(tokensSold < 700000*10**6){
  price = 20;
}
//the price above is Token per ETH
// calculate token amount to be sent
uint256 tokens = (weiAmount/10**12) * price;//weiamount * price 



require(tokens >= 1 * 10 ** 6); //1 token minimum


// update state
weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);


tokenReward.transfer(beneficiary, tokens);
tokensSold = tokensSold.add(tokens);//now we can track the number of tokens sold.
TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);
forwardFunds();

}

// send ether to the fund collection wallet // override to create custom fund forwarding mechanisms function forwardFunds() internal { // wallet.transfer(msg.value); if (!wallet.send(msg.value)) { throw; } }

// @return true if the transaction can buy tokens function validPurchase() internal constant returns (bool) { bool withinPeriod = started; bool nonZeroPurchase = msg.value != 0; return withinPeriod && nonZeroPurchase; }

function withdrawTokens(uint256 _amount) { if(msg.sender!=wallet) throw; tokenReward.transfer(wallet,_amount); } }
```

But I don't think there's a problem with this contract. I have a problem with transferring the tokens to it, because wallet.ethereum.org doesn't show me the tokens at all - the balance is 0 and I can't send them. Also, when trying to do it via MyEtherWallet it says the ERC20 Token is not valid - so there has to be a problem somewhere, but neither you or me seem to see it :/
Also: Sorry, I can't manage to format it

Answer (score 1):

Jut run it on Remix and it seems to be working fine.
Compiled correctly and when checking its totalSupply the assigned amount is indeed in there.

I also transferred 1000 tokens to another address using transfer() and then balanceOf() that address and it does show the tokens.

The contract you pasted above is just for the token itself, but you mention a crowdsale contract. What exactly are you trying to do?

[image]

Comment: I have now edited the question. Didn't manage to format the code though, sorry for that, hope you can also read it that way :/

Comment: When I try to use transfer, it shows the following:
transact to browser/ballot.sol:ImmortalityCoin.transfer errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: Are you calling transfer on the token itself? What are you passing to the function?

Comment: I am just adding my wallet address (Main account) from wallet.ethereum.org
Thought the transfer will send the tokens to me (even though I should actually already own them, because it shows my address as owner. wallet.ethereum.org doesn't show me any tokens though, my balance is 0,00000...
Also as mentioned, I have tried to use MyEtherWallet because of that problems - MyEtherWallet says the address is not a valid ERC20 Token after adding it. There has to be some problem, but I don't see why it works for you and why it worked for me a couple days ago. And I am compiling the right contract

Comment: Are you deploying the token contract and then deploying the crowdsale contract using the newly generated token address?

Comment: Yes I am - and after starting the crowdsale I can send ether to it, but it won't give me any tokens due to a failing Tx Recipient or something like that. I think the problem is that I can't send the tokens I have to the crowdsale address, so it can't give out tokens.

Comment: When you send eth to the crowdsale, it executes the fallback function, which in turn will execute buyTokens(). First, make sure that you are providing enough gas to the transaction or it will fail. Second, make sure there's no precondition failing in the buyTokens function, maybe the start / end date, etc. You should debug it on Remix to see exactly where it is failing.